# What is the space around a parbox?

Tags: spacing

I write a short macro which put a picture on the left and a text on the right:

```
\newlength\largeur

\newcommand{\uneQuestion}[1]{
    \setlength{\largeur}{\columnwidth}
    \addtolength{\largeur}{-16mm}
    \noindent
    \hspace*{2mm}
    \parbox{12mm}{\iconequestion}
    \hspace*{2mm}
    \parbox{\largeur}{\color{CouleurQuestion!95} #1}
}
```

As you can see `largeur` will be the width of the text and in order to compute it, I substract to the column width the two `\hspace`s and the `\parbox` space.

But If I did that, the text is slightly larger than the `\columnwidth`. I guess that there is a short space around a `\parbox`?

Comment: You have some spurious spaces (after the two `\hspace`s and *both* `\parbox`es), which is removed when you end the line with `%`. See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://goo.gl/awJkj)

Comment: ... *and* the length setting, of course.

Comment: If the linked question solved your problem, we can close this question as a duplicate. Please give some feedback if this is not the case. Duplication on this site is fine, and could guide future visitors.

Comment: Yes it does. You can mark this question as a duplicate.